# how to convert type char to type id

Tags: objective-c

actually I have to store three character in NSArray

`
    char plus  = '+';
    char minus = '-';
    char multiply = '*';

```
NSArray *operator = [NSArray arraywithobjects : plus , minus ,multiply,nil];`
```

obviously before I store three characters in NSarray I have these character to convert to id.
  so how to convert char to id.or guide me to other better or efficient technique so save three characters.

Comment: Do you want to store as characters or would strings be OK. Also could a plain C array be used?

Comment: Why do they have to be char? It would be much easier if you used single character strings (@"+", @"-", @"*").

Comment: Or if they are chars, let them be `int`s wrapped in an `NSNumber`: `NSArray *ops = @[@(plus), @(minus), @(multiply)]`. Don't call your array `operator`, by the way - it's a C++ keyword.

Comment: You can use an NSNumber or an NSString.  Or there is a sort of wrapper class for scalars whose name I can never remember.

Comment: if i put this in string.it cover more memory then character..but any way it solve my problem..thanks

Comment: @MartinR - Yep.  Now I just need to remember "Martin R" when I'm trying to remember what it is.

Comment: Yeah, making it a string is probably the least complicated approach, overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap characters using NSNumber, for example, `@(plus)` and add it to operator NSArray.
Get it back to char with `[(NSNumber *)operator[index] charValue]`

Answer (score 2):

```
        // As we can not add primitive to NSArray ,
        // First we should convert it to NSString and then add it to NSArray

        //'c' character string
        char plus = '+';

        char minus = '-';

        char multiply = '*';


        //Converted to NSString object which was inherited from NSObject
        NSString *plusObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", plus];


        NSString *minusObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", minus];


        NSString *multiplyObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", multiply];


        //Add collection of NSString objects to NSArray
        NSArray *operator = [NSArray 
                 arrayWithObjects:plusObject , minusObject ,multiplyObject,nil];
```